# Find lines matching list of substrings

Tags: string, algorithm, search

This is an interview question.

I have a text file with web addresses, such as:

```
www.yahoo.com
www.google.com
www.apple.com
www.microsoft.com
```

and I have a list of substrings, such as oo, goog, app.  How can I find all the lines that match one of the substrings?  For this example, I would have:

```
www.yahoo.com
www.google.com
www.apple.com
```

The interviewer didn't like going line-by-line and checking whether any of the substrings occurred in a line.  I then said we could use a trie, but that would only be useful if the first character of the substring matched the first character in the line, which is similar to how the suggestion feature works in Google.

Thanks

Comment: A trie would be silly. Either use a known string matching algo like Boyer-Moore or regex.

Comment: You could also use KMP for string matching. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm

Comment: I wasn't expecting to use these "named" algorithms.  I thought the solution would be something I could figure out on the spot.  Yes, the algorithms posted here were invented using simple constructs, but it's unlikely someone would come up with them during an interview.  If the interviewer was expecting me to use Boyer-Moore, KMP, etc., I do not think this was a good question.

Answer (score 2):

You could use regular expressions. For example, the expression `oo|goog|app` would do it.

If you have a very large number of substrings and you're going to search a lot of text, you'd use something like the [Aho-Corasick string matching algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm).

It's interesting to note that the brute force approach (using a standard string matching algorithm) and the Aho-Corasick algorithm would output two matches for "www.google.com" ("oo" and "goog"), but the regex solution would only output one.

In regards to your comment about the appropriateness of the question, it might not be designed to get a "right" answer, but rather to see how you think about problems. For example, using a standard string search algorithm would take time proportional to MxN, where M is the number of strings to search, and N is the number of substrings to find. A regular expression solution would be faster, because you'd only have to run the regex one time on each string you're searching. The Aho-Corasick algorithm is faster still, because its state machine finds all matches in a single pass. The approach you use depends on many factors including how many strings and substrings you have, how often you have to run this, and how much time you have to implement the solution. It's a good question for revealing how you approach a difficult problem and how you identify and evaluate potential solutions.

Comment: Well, this is the first time I'm hearing of these algorithms.  Let me check them out.  I'm not sure if the interviewer would have liked using regular expressions since they usually expect you to come up with something that doesn't additional tools, like grep.